# Why it show a missing template error in my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

controller method

```
def export
  @customers =Customer.all

  flash[:success] = "Script ran successfully"
end
```

I am trying to export all the customers into a csv file but I am receiving a missing template error. why? in my view folder I have a button.

```
<p><%= button_to 'export Import', scripts_export_data_path %></p>
```

I would like to export the customers data into the above button.

Comment: Please post full error trace

Comment: @PetrGazarov i have edit my post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014912/how-to-download-a-csv-file-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: What is the URL you are using? http://example.com/customers/1/export ? Your URL needs to be http://example.com/customers/1/export.csv or http://example.com/customers/1/export?format=csv

Comment: It means you don't have the right name for your ERB file for HTML mode. If this is ScriptsController, then `app/views/scripts/export.erb`

Comment: I have update my program by removing the respond_to  do |format|
format.html and format.csv { send_data @customers.to_csv}. when I run my export butoon I am only getting the Script ran successfully. How to export my csv file data

Comment: @tadman how do i fix this error message: The action 'export' could not be found for ScriptsController

Comment: how did you define your route for `export` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to render or redirect_to the page that you want to show after the line where you have the flash message. The flash message is shown at the next page load whatever that may be.

```
def export
@customers =Customer.all

flash[:success] = "Script ran successfully"

redirect_to 'page/template' or.... render 'page/template'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example,

[Exporting CSV](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast)